# Second @media query triggers error

Tags: css, media-queries

I can't figure out where there's an error in the following CSS:

```
@media all and (min-width: 570px) and (max-width: 970px) {
    .contain {
        padding: 0 0 0;
    }

    .two {
        display: none;
        width: 0;
        margin-right: 0;
    }

    .two .tube {
        padding: 0 0 0;
    }

    nav#primary .contain {
        padding: 0 240px 0 0;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    nav#primary .contain .two {
        display: inherit;
        width: 240px;
        margin-right: -240px;
    }
}

/*
 *  Keep headers in proportion
 */

@media all and (min-width: 971px) and (max-width: 1060) {
    header#mast h1 {
        font-size: 3.2em;
    }
}
```

The first @media query works, the second @media block is ignored. The W3C CSS Validator complaints that "only 0 can be a length. You must put a unit after your number  ) { header#mast h1 { font-size: 1em; } }".

Am I missing something really obvious?

Comment: `max-width: 1060` => `max-width: 1060px` ?

Comment: Oh dear... Yep, that was it. A little embarrassing, if I say so myself ;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is the HTML ?

Well... Here is a version of what you wrote *without* all of the unnecessary or redundant parts. But I can't test it without the HTML.

```
@media (min-width: 570px) { /* =========START=== */

    .contain {
        padding: 0;
    }

    .two {
        display: none;
        width: 0;
        margin-right: 0;
    }

    .two .tube {
        padding: 0;
    }

    .primary .contain {
        padding: 0 240px 0 0;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .primary .contain .two {
        width: 240px;
        margin-right: -240px;
    }

} /* =====================================END=== */



@media (min-width: 971px) { /* =========START=== */

    .mast h1 {
        font-size: 3.2em;
    }

} /* =====================================END=== */
```

Comment: @dsfq should put their comment in an answer so you can check it off.